# MySQL: Sort '1st' BEFORE '101st'

Tags: mysql, sorting

In one of my database fields, I have numbers which include ordinal suffixes. I'm trying to sort them ascending, but since the numbers include ordinal suffixes, the string '101st' is assigned a greater value than '1st', and similarly, '29th' a greater value than '2d'.

Does anyone know how I might work around this, without removing the ordinal suffixes of each digit?

Comment: Why not changing it to a int field and add the suffix at your code instead ? it would be easier to sort and manage

Comment: Because there's other data in the field too.

Comment: you should fix your poor database design, if you want access a number without suffix get use other column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
order by cast(field as unsigned)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL, but any real database is going to barf on CAST(field as any numeric) when the field contains alpha characters. Does MySQL allow this?

Comment: @Ken - mysql isn't a real database then?

Comment: @nickf: Did I say that? Don't read more into my question than what's there. Oracle and SQL Server would raise an exception/generate an error on trying to CAST '123rd ABCDEF' into a numeric value.

Comment: @Ken - fair enough. :) Anyway, in MySQL, `SELECT CAST('123abc' as UNSIGNED)` results in `123`. `SELECT CAST('a' as UNSIGNED)` is `0`.

Comment: @BenM. Glad I could help you but my advice is of following other advices in order to redesign your table structure. As nickf wrote you casting will slow down performance.

Comment: @nickf: Thanks. I wouldn't have suspected that would work. I'm not sure it should. :) It seems to me that encourages sloppy/bad development practices. I personally think casting `a` as UNSIGNED should not return 0; it should raise an exception that says "You're an idiot! 'a' isn't a number.", but that's just me. ;)

Comment: @nick rulez: A reluctant +1. +1 for a right answer; reluctant because it shouldn't be possible for it to be right. :)

Comment: @ken: I totally agree with you but this is the behaviour of mysql ;) Thanks for the upvote even though I understand your perplexities. I would never store infos in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Like er... @nick rulez ... said, you can sort a query by a derived column, in this case casting it to an integer on the fly.

That should work for small sets, but if you have a larger set, or a lot of traffic, then it might be worth storing that number in its own indexed column to speed up your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The column type is probably an alphanumeric type and therefore sorts according to alphabetical order rules.  The column needs to be a numeric type so that it will sort by numerical rules.  I'd strongly advise using a numerical type (int) for the column, it will offer a lot of advantages over alphanumeric types in this case, and the only drawback is losing the suffix.  However, once you've got the value out, adding the suffix to the retrieved value should be easy.

[Does mysql have function for returning a number with ordinal suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015298/does-mysql-have-function-for-returning-a-number-with-ordinal-suffix) suggests ways of adding the suffix to the value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to the one mentioned here. I wanted to implement natural sorting without having to process that data in another language such as PHP's natsort(). I found this solutions and it worked perfect for me.

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(field), field
```