# Combining SQL COUNT(*) with an INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I've made a query to count and rank every row for a table, but I can't join the query into one table.

I've been trying to make a leaderboard and I've managed to make a query that ranks every row based on the amount of points they have (ie. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc). Due to my SQL version, I've had to use a workaround to ROW_NUMBER() and I'm struggling to include that query in this INNER JOIN query I've already got.

INNER JOIN query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT students.username, 
            CONCAT(spoints.points, 'pts') AS pointspts, 
            CONCAT(students.firstname, ' ', students.lastname) AS name, 
            CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS sexes, 
            students.house, 
            CONCAT(students.age, 'yrs') AS ageyrs 
        FROM students 
            INNER JOIN spoints ON students.username=spoints.username 
        ORDER BY points DESC");
```

The `COUNT(*)` query in which I'm trying to merge into the `INNER JOIN` query:

```
$rank = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, 1 + ( SELECT count(*) FROM spoints a WHERE a.points > b.points ) AS rank 
                        FROM spoints b 
                        ORDER BY rank;");
```

I'm trying to link these up so they'll form one succinct table, which is where the issue is arising.

I've tried a large variation of code joining them, such as:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT students.username, 
            CONCAT(spoints.points, 'pts') AS pointspts, 
            CONCAT(students.firstname, ' ', students.lastname) AS name, 
            CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS sexes, 
            students.house, CONCAT(students.age, 'yrs') AS ageyrs, 
            (SELECT 1 + (SELECT count(*) FROM spoints a WHERE a.points > b.points ) AS rank FROM spoints b) AS rank 
        FROM students 
            INNER JOIN spoints ON students.username=spoints.username 
        ORDER BY points DESC");
```

But that only seems to return a blank column or a `"mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row"` error.

I've also tried merging the queries with two `mysqli_fetch_arrays` but then I have this mutually exclusive problem in which only the first column of either the `$rank query`, or the `$query query` will print. I.e.

```
while ($roow = mysqli_fetch_array($rank)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        printf("
            <tr>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
            </tr>", $roow['rank'], $row['name'], $row['ageyrs'], $row['sexes'], $row['house'], $row['pointspts']
        ); 
    }
}
```

returns:

| Standing | Name | Age | Sex | House | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 234pts |
| 1st | Ami Beckler | 12yrs | Female | Pacific | 24pts |
| 1st | Jan Schuette | 18yrs | Male | Coral | 0pts |

OR

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       while ($roow = mysqli_fetch_array($rank)){
        printf("
            <tr>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
            </tr>", $roow['rank'], $row['name'], $row['ageyrs'], $row['sexes'], $row['house'], $row['pointspts']
        ); 
    }
}
```

returns:

| Standing | Name | Age | Sex | House | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 234pts |
| 2nd | Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 234pts |
| 3rd | Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 234pts |

I want my code to return this:

| Standing | Name | Age | Sex | House | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 234pts |
| 2nd | Ami Beckler | 12yrs | Female | Pacific | 24pts |
| 3rd | Jan Schuette | 18yrs | Male | Coral | 0pts |

with the code I've already created which is clearly capable of doing so.

How do I merge these queries so they may all print together?

Comment: The table schemas and data might be useful to help others construct a replica and test this ranking. How many places are you using for ranks - 1st,2nd & 3rd or unlimited?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have 200 people in the competitors table, so ideally there should be 200 rows printed.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please debug one software layer at a time.--Since you need to compose a [mre], it is much simpler to be just SQL. Please before you publish look at the formatted version of your post.--See the help re markdown table format. Please avoid social & meta commentary. It's not helpful to say you researched without relating specific relevant results or failed search strings. It's not helpful to give a narrative of your experiences.--Give 1 [mre] for 1 bad query or for relevant working parts & their specifications & your reasoning connecting them to the goal.

Comment: My apologies, I'm very new to posting and a lot of what you said didn't make a lot of sense to me. But I will have a look at everything you linked and update my post accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example of how I believe it's a better way to get the expected data, I hope it helps.

Edited in more detail for better understanding.

```
select concat( s.firstname , ' ', s.lastname) as name,
    concat(s.age,'yrs') as Age ,
    CASE WHEN s.sex = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS Sex
    ,s.house  as House
# use sum(p.points) to count the number of points, 
# or count(p.points) if there is one # point per line 

,sum(p.points) as points

# Use the points table as the main one 
# and include the link with the left join of the students table
from spoints p

# I see that your secondary key link is by username,
# in my case I used p.student_id = s.id
# but in your case use
# p.username = s.username

    left join students s on p.student_id = s.id

# perform the grouping with reference to the username for your case
# group by p.username
group by p.student_id

# para obter os melhor colocados  
# utilize 'order by' para deixalos no top com ordenação 'desc'
order by points desc
# if your version has support use limit 3 to get only the first 3
limit 3
```

Result

| name | Age | Sex | House | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ami Beckler | 12yrs | Female | Pacific | 151 |
| Kogan Spaghetti | 17yrs | Male | Tasman | 141 |
| Jan Schuette | 18yrs | Male | Coral | 54 |

sample database

```
CREATE DATABASE teste;
use teste
create table students
(
    id        int auto_increment
        primary key,
    username  text null,
    firstname text null,
    lastname  text null,
    age       int  null,
    house     text null,
    sex       text null,
    constraint students_id_uindex
        unique (id)
);

INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 'Kogan', 'Spaghetti', 17, 'Tasman ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 'Ami', 'Beckler', 12, 'Pacific ', 'F')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 'Jan', 'Schuette', 18, 'Coral ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('px.t1', 'px', 't1', 16, 'Pacific ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('px.t2', 'px', 't2', 17, 'Pacific ', 'F')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('px.t3', 'px', 't3', 18, 'Pacific ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('cx.t4', 'cx', 't4', 15, 'Coral ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('cx.t5', 'cx', 't5', 14, 'Coral ', 'D')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('cx.t6', 'cx', 't6', 13, 'Coral ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('tx.t7', 'tx', 't7', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('tx.t8', 'tx', 't8', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M')
INSERT INTO teste.students (username, firstname, lastname, age, house, sex) VALUES ('tx.t9', 'tx', 't9', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M')

create table spoints
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    username   text null,
    points     int  null,
    student_id int  null,
    constraint spoints_id_uindex
        unique (id),
    constraint spoints_students_id_fk
        foreign key (student_id) references students (id)
);


INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 2, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 5, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 2, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 9, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 6, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 6, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 1, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 3, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 8, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 7, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 2, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('jan.schuette  ', 3, 3)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 3, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 12, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 34, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 5, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 3, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 6, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 77, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 8, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 2, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('ami.beckler', 1, 2)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 5, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 4, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 75, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 7, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 6, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 34, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('kogan.spaghetti', 5, 1)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('px.t1', 2, 4)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('px.t2', 2, 5)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('px.t3', 2, 6)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('cx.t4', 2, 7)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('cx.t5', 2, 8)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('cx.t6', 2, 9)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('tx.t7', 2, 10)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('tx.t8', 2, 11)
INSERT INTO teste.spoints (username, points, student_id) VALUES ('tx.t9', 2, 12)
```

php exemple

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$i++;
/*
use filter to add the st, nd, rd complement
using the variable $i as a line counter knowing that your query is already sorted
*/
$filter = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
if (($i %100) >= 11 && ($i%100) <= 13)
   $rank = $i. 'th';
else
    $rank = ($i)? $i. $filter[$i % 10] : $i;

printf("
            <tr>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
            </tr>",$rank, $row['name'], $row['Age'], $row['Sex'], $row['House'], $row['points'].'pts'
        ); 
}
```

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiguq.png)

Comment: Hi Rafa, this all looks quite orderly and technical, but I’m still struggling include the column that actually ranks them 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. Would you know how to do that without ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: edited for better understanding,

I believe that the use of 'group by' in your case by username,
adding order by points desc

you will get the best placed already sorted.

just being necessary to know how many students you want to get, in case you want 3, use limit 3 .

and when printing with php, use the $filter variable to which I left the example to add the st, nd, rd complement...

because you already have the sorted data

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry for my misunderstanding, this looks very promising, will give this a try my friend!

Comment: I ended up correcting my mistake.
when using oder by, do not use concat(), leave the value as an integer to perform the sorting correctly.

add the 'pts' add-on later

Comment: Hi Rafa, worked like a charm, much appreciate your help. Couldn't be happier right now!

Answer (score 0):

If you made this a two stage process where the first stage is to generate a `view` of the data that accounts for the addition of scores then the second stage could use that `view` to then perform the rank calculation.

Borrowing slightly the table schema ( lightly modified ) from @Rafa Akito's answer - viz:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_students` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` TEXT NULL,
    `firstname` TEXT NULL,
    `lastname` TEXT NULL,
    `age` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `house` TEXT NULL,
    `sex` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `students_id_uindex` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_scores` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` TEXT NULL,
    `points` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `student_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `scores_id_uindex` (`id`),
    INDEX `scores_students_id_fk` (`student_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `scores_students_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_students` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `tbl_scores` (`id`, `username`, `points`, `student_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'jan.schuette', 2, 3),
    (2, 'jan.schuette', 5, 3),
    (3, 'jan.schuette', 2, 3),
    (4, 'jan.schuette', 9, 3),
    (5, 'jan.schuette', 6, 3),
    (6, 'jan.schuette', 6, 3),
    (7, 'jan.schuette', 1, 3),
    (8, 'jan.schuette', 3, 3),
    (9, 'jan.schuette', 8, 3),
    (10, 'jan.schuette', 7, 3),
    (11, 'jan.schuette', 2, 3),
    (12, 'jan.schuette', 3, 3),
    (13, 'ami.beckler', 3, 2),
    (14, 'ami.beckler', 12, 2),
    (15, 'ami.beckler', 34, 2),
    (16, 'ami.beckler', 5, 2),
    (17, 'ami.beckler', 3, 2),
    (18, 'ami.beckler', 6, 2),
    (19, 'ami.beckler', 77, 2),
    (20, 'ami.beckler', 8, 2),
    (21, 'ami.beckler', 2, 2),
    (22, 'ami.beckler', 1, 2),
    (23, 'kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1),
    (24, 'kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1),
    (25, 'kogan.spaghetti', 5, 1),
    (26, 'kogan.spaghetti', 4, 1),
    (27, 'kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1),
    (28, 'kogan.spaghetti', 75, 1),
    (29, 'kogan.spaghetti', 7, 1),
    (30, 'kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1),
    (31, 'kogan.spaghetti', 6, 1),
    (32, 'kogan.spaghetti', 34, 1),
    (33, 'kogan.spaghetti', 1, 1),
    (34, 'kogan.spaghetti', 5, 1),
    (35, 'px.t1', 2, 4),
    (36, 'px.t2', 2, 5),
    (37, 'px.t3', 2, 6),
    (38, 'cx.t4', 2, 7),
    (39, 'cx.t5', 2, 8),
    (40, 'cx.t6', 2, 9),
    (41, 'tx.t7', 2, 10),
    (42, 'tx.t8', 2, 11),
    (43, 'tx.t9', 2, 12);

INSERT INTO `tbl_students` (`id`, `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, `house`, `sex`) VALUES
    (1, 'kogan.spaghetti', 'Kogan', 'Spaghetti', 17, 'Tasman ', 'M'),
    (2, 'ami.beckler', 'Ami', 'Beckler', 12, 'Pacific ', 'F'),
    (3, 'jan.schuette', 'Jan', 'Schuette', 18, 'Coral ', 'M'),
    (4, 'px.t1', 'px', 't1', 16, 'Pacific ', 'M'),
    (5, 'px.t2', 'px', 't2', 17, 'Pacific ', 'F'),
    (6, 'px.t3', 'px', 't3', 18, 'Pacific ', 'M'),
    (7, 'cx.t4', 'cx', 't4', 15, 'Coral ', 'M'),
    (8, 'cx.t5', 'cx', 't5', 14, 'Coral ', 'D'),
    (9, 'cx.t6', 'cx', 't6', 13, 'Coral ', 'M'),
    (10, 'tx.t7', 'tx', 't7', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M'),
    (11, 'tx.t8', 'tx', 't8', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M'),
    (12, 'tx.t9', 'tx', 't9', 13, 'Tasman ', 'M');
```

Then creating the `view`:

```
create view vw_stud_rank as
select 
    st.`username`, 
    sum( sc.`points` ) as `score`
from tbl_students st
    join tbl_scores sc on sc.`student_id`=st.`id`
group by st.`id`;
```

And finally the ranking calculation query:

```
select 
    s.*,
    case 
        when @pr = `score` then @cr 
        when @pr := `score` then @cr := @cr + 1
    end as `rank`
 from `vw_stud_rank` s,
 ( select @cr:=0,@pr:=null ) x
order by `score` desc;
```

The above query then yields:

```
+-----------------+-------+------+
| username        | score | rank |
+-----------------+-------+------+
| ami.beckler     |   151 |    1 |
| kogan.spaghetti |   141 |    2 |
| jan.schuette    |    54 |    3 |
| px.t1           |     2 |    4 |
| px.t2           |     2 |    4 |
| px.t3           |     2 |    4 |
| cx.t4           |     2 |    4 |
| cx.t5           |     2 |    4 |
| cx.t6           |     2 |    4 |
| tx.t7           |     2 |    4 |
| tx.t8           |     2 |    4 |
| tx.t9           |     2 |    4 |
+-----------------+-------+------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If you combine that with your own function ( [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015298/does-mysql-have-function-for-returning-a-number-with-ordinal-suffix) ) - viz:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ordinal(number BIGINT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE ord VARCHAR(64);
  SET ord = (SELECT CONCAT(number, CASE
    WHEN number%100 BETWEEN 11 AND 13 THEN "th"
    WHEN number%10 = 1 THEN "st"
    WHEN number%10 = 2 THEN "nd"
    WHEN number%10 = 3 THEN "rd"
    ELSE "th"
  END));
  RETURN ord;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You could then modify the above query to become:

```
select 
    s.*,
    case 
        when @pr = `score` then ordinal(@cr) 
        when @pr := `score` then @cr := ordinal(@cr + 1)
    end as `rank`
 from `vw_stud_rank` s,
 ( select @cr:=0, @pr:=null ) x
order by `score` desc;
```

Which itself yields:

```
+-----------------+-------+------+
| username        | score | rank |
+-----------------+-------+------+
| ami.beckler     |   151 | 1st  |
| kogan.spaghetti |   141 | 2nd  |
| jan.schuette    |    54 | 3rd  |
| px.t1           |     2 | 4th  |
| px.t2           |     2 | 4th  |
| px.t3           |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t4           |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t5           |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t6           |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t7           |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t8           |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t9           |     2 | 4th  |
+-----------------+-------+------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `view` is simple to modify to include the `yrs` or `Male`/`Female` of course and it should be noted that later versions of `mySQL` - 8+ - have the `rank()` function built-in but the above was done within mySQL 5.5.8

A modified `view`:

```
create view vw_stud_rank as
select 
    st.`username`,
    concat(st.age,'yrs') as `age`,
    st.house,
    case
        when st.sex='m' then 'Male'
        when st.sex='f' then 'Female'
        else 'Non-Binary'
    end as `sex`,
    sum( sc.`points` ) as `score`
from tbl_students st
    join tbl_scores sc on sc.`student_id`=st.`id`
group by st.`id`;
```

That then yields the result more akin to the desired result:

```
+-----------------+-------+----------+------------+-------+------+
| username        | age   | house    | sex        | score | rank |
+-----------------+-------+----------+------------+-------+------+
| ami.beckler     | 12yrs | Pacific  | Female     |   151 | 1st  |
| kogan.spaghetti | 17yrs | Tasman   | Male       |   141 | 2nd  |
| jan.schuette    | 18yrs | Coral    | Male       |    54 | 3rd  |
| px.t1           | 16yrs | Pacific  | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| px.t2           | 17yrs | Pacific  | Female     |     2 | 4th  |
| px.t3           | 18yrs | Pacific  | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t4           | 15yrs | Coral    | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t5           | 14yrs | Coral    | Non-Binary |     2 | 4th  |
| cx.t6           | 13yrs | Coral    | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t7           | 13yrs | Tasman   | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t8           | 13yrs | Tasman   | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
| tx.t9           | 13yrs | Tasman   | Male       |     2 | 4th  |
+-----------------+-------+----------+------------+-------+------+
12 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Which, when plugged into PHP, could yield final HTML as follows:

```
<?php
    
    chdir('../../dbo');
    require 'db-conn-details.php';
    require 'mysqli-conn.php';
    
    
    
    $sql="select
            case 
                when @pr = `score` then ordinal( @cr )
                when @pr := `score` then @cr := ordinal( @cr + 1 )
            end as `standing`,
            s.username,
            s.age,
            s.house,
            s.sex,
            concat( s.score, 'pts' ) as `points`

        from `vw_stud_rank` s,
         ( select @cr:=0,@pr:=null ) x
        order by `score` desc;";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            table{
                border:1px solid grey;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                font-family:monospace;
                width:80%;
                float:none;
                margin:auto
            }
            tr th{
                background:grey;
                color:white;
            }
            td{
                border:1px dotted grey
            }
            th,td{
                padding:0.5rem;
                text-align:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col width='5%' />
                <col width='55%' />
                <col width='10%' />
                <col width='10%' />
                <col width='10%' />
                <col width='10%' />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <th>Standing</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>House</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $res=$db->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                printf('
                    <tr>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>',
                    $rs->standing,
                    $rs->username,
                    $rs->age,
                    $rs->house,
                    $rs->sex,
                    $rs->points
                );
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]